# Cannot access gitlab repo using ssh keys using Windows

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have followed [these instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#generate-an-ssh-key-pair) for generating keypairs using ssh-keygen. I actually generated both the ed25519 and an rsa key as I attempted to figure out what was wrong.

I copied and pasted the public key pair for both of these keys in gitlab according to their instructions.

when I enter: `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` it says:

`client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0`

but it also says `Welcome to gitlab, @my_username!`

when I try to push to my repo, I get a popup asking for my gitlab username and password which I enter and which fails.

I don't understand why it is prompting me for a username and password considering that I have attempted to establish SSH keypairs for authentication.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Maybe you cloned via https, not ssh?

Comment: I'm almost certain I used the SSH method

Comment: Try `git remote -v`, which should show the remote url with at least an `@` in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pulling from Git fails and gives me following error: client\_global\_hostkeys\_private\_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401049/pulling-from-git-fails-and-gives-me-following-error-client-global-hostkeys-priv)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I get a popup asking for my gitlab username and password which I enter and which fails.

Check, as commented:

- `git remote -v`
- `git config credential.helper`

If the first starts with `https://`, and the second is not empty, what you see is a Git credential helper trying to cache your HTTPS credentials.
That means your SSH key would be ignored anyway.

Regarding the error message, check out [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/lyazre/openssh_update_causes_problems/), and test it with:

```
ssh -o UpdateHostKeys=no -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

To make it persistent, in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitlab.com
  UpdateHostKeys no
```

Comment: I see the https:// prefix after running `git remote -v`. Testing with the `UpdateHostKeys=no ` command seemed to work. I am not sure how to correct the issue of it using https:// instead of ssh and it trying to "help" with the credential helper. I'd like to be able to use my ssh keys and just push to the repo. Thanks for the links.

Comment: @unbutu If you see https:// and want to use your SSH keys, you need to switch to SSH with: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>.git`

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.

Comment: @VonC maybe you should transcript the answer mentioned in your link to your answer here because links might break over time. In any case, it actually worked for me thanks. (I mean the part where he suggests adding "Host gitlab.com\nUpdateHostKeys no" to the `~/.ssh/config` file, which is a permanent solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/lyazre/openssh_update_causes_problems/gpuwe3x?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: @VinGarcia Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly. Don't hesitate to add your own edit if I have missed something.

Comment: Thanks, what you wrote is perfect, I upvoted the answer =]