# Pulling from Git fails and gives me following error: client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0

Tags: git, rsa, pull-request, ssh-keys, git-pull

I am working on a project with my teammates. Some weeks ago, I pulled the project from git successfully. But today when I wanted to  **pull the updated project** via the command "**git pull origin <my_branch**>", it gave me the following **error**:

**client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0**

I have generated the public key using the command **ssh-keygen** and then pasted the content of the new generated file **id_rsa.pub**  in the "*Add an SSH key*" section of *Git*, But the *pull command did not work*. Could somebody help me?

Comment: [Not exactly a duplicate, but perhaps close enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66876321/1256452) (which leads you to https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/lyazre/openssh_update_causes_problems/)

Answer (score 92):

The message "client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0" is ***not*** an error, it is a warning, and it is related to some ssh versioning issue.  It used to be very common to receive from GitLab.

If you want it to go away, you can make sure that your `~/.ssh/config` contains the following:

```
Host gitlab.com
    UpdateHostKeys no
```

However, if you are in fact being prevented from pulling, then this bad signature warning is probably ***not*** the reason. Once you make the warning go away, you will still have to find the real problem that you have, about which we know nothing, as the question stands right now.

Comment: What potential side-effects would this have? Does it risk masking a serious problem in some other context?

Comment: If this is the first time you have created `~/.ssh/config`, make sure you also give it the correct permissions with `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config` to prevent the error "Bad owner or permissions on [..]"

Comment: @J.B.Rainsberger two years ago I did not answer the question in your comment because I did not know the answer. In the mean time, did you by any chance find the answer?

Comment: @MikeNakis No, I have no additional wisdom to share. Thank you for checking.